# What is a wrong in this if/else code?

Tags: javascript

What is my problem with these instructions ?
Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.
The rules:
For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.
Otherwise, just print out the number.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if (i % 3) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    if (i % 5) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    if ((i % 3) && (i % 5)) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `i % 3` does?

Comment: try using else if instead of just if.  You're nesting is wrong otherwise.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, it runs with no errors.  So if it's not returning what you expected, you need to look at this harder.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: The sequence of your conditions is wrong. Suppose number 15. In your case, then, 3 of your conditions would be true. check out my updated answer

Comment: Of course it's homework.  Something like this literally serves no other purpose than an exercise in simple problem solving.  That's why there are 4 very similar answers that are all correct, yet slightly different.

Comment: It's also a common programming interview question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to do this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if ((i % 3) === 0 && (i % 5) === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } 
    else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Consider this condition should be the first one:

```
if ((i % 3) === 0 && (i % 5) === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
```

Otherwise, it would work wrong for number 15

Answer (score 2):

A number is divisible by 3 when `number % 3 == 0`. Furthermore, you need to learn about `else if` and think about the order of your conditions. That's all you need to solve this problem.

Just showing you the solution wouldn't help you in learning programming.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator return value is not a boolean, but the remainder of the division operation. So you need to check if the remainder is 0.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if ((i % 3) == 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    if ((i % 5) == 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The % operator returns the remainder, so if we do:

```
9 % 3
```

The result is 0 - since 3 is the square root of 9...your if conditions are checking for a non-zero result.

you should be doing:

```
if (! (i % 3))
```

To check for a return of 0.

Also, consider using sme `else if`'s in your code and proper nesting and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the number is divisible by three or five.  You're checking if it's true.

This is what you should be doing:

```
for ( var i =1 ; i < 21 ; i++ ) {  
  if(i%3==0){
    console.log("Fizz");
    }
  if(i%5==0){
    console.log("Buzz");
  }
  if((i%3==0) && (i%5==0)){
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The mod function "%" returns the remainder.  If there is no remainder, it is a clean division.  So you want to make sure the result is 0.

Comment: What does your program print if I gave it the number 15?

Comment: it prints Fizz, Buzz, and FizzBuzz.  Which, logically is what it should print.  I see what you're getting at.  I was correcting his code.  But I didn't fix all the logic.

Answer (score 0):

`i % x` returns the remainder of `i / x`, so you need to check against `== 0`.

Additionally, you should check `i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0` first, and use `else if`, otherwise all of your statements will execute all of the time, regardless of if the previous statements were already true.

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
  if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```